# Change CKEditor / CKFinder Images Upload Path in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, ckfinder

Hello, I am using CKEditor / CKFINDER on my site as my texteditor and image upload.

CKEditor and CKFinder Folder need to put on the root, outside my Public_html .

My dir structure be like :
 - ckeditor, -CKfinder, -public_html

And my text editor image stored in : ckfinder/userfiles/files

Question :

- how to change CKFinder default image upload path ? i want to puth my image files to inside public_html
- example my domain is : domain.com, how can i get my images url that stored in ckfinder dir that outside my public_html?

i spent my times in many days to solve this but i havent found the sollution.

i found so many topic about this but nothing solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the `root` option of the local filesystem backend described [here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_backends_local) in the documentation. You can configure CKFinder to store uploaded files in any directory you like by setting its path as backend `root`.

Comment: And how do you do it on CKFinder 2? (my issue here is that due to limitations on the software that can be installed on the server, unfortunately I have to rely on older versions of CKEditor and CKFinder)

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn: In CKFinder 2 you can achieve the same by setting `directory` of `ResourceType` in your connector config.

https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/Configuration/Resource_Types/Built-in